# How to set the timeout of the preemptive link?

Tags: dynamic

I apologize if this is a RTFM question, but I couldn't find this in the docs.

**How can I set the timeout of the preemptive link?**

For example:

```
Button["TestShort", Pause[1]; Print["Result"], Method -> "Preemptive"]
Button["TestLong", Pause[10]; Print["Result"], Method -> "Preemptive"]
```

Clicking on `TestLong` times out on my system.

Comment: Something like `Button["TestLong", 
 TimeConstrained[Pause[5]; Print["Result5"], 2, Print@"Failed"], 
 Method -> "Preemptive"]` ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question

Comment: @belisarius The Preemptive method has a certain timeout. I would like to know what the time limit is and how can I set it.

Comment: @belisarius Your snippet above always prints `Failed`

Comment: @belisarius Sorry for the confusion, `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` was set to 5 on my system.

Comment: Ahhh OK. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Option Inspector, there's `CellOptions` → `Evaluation Options` → `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` which contains that timeout.

As stated in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html), the value can also be set programmatically using (for this session only):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {DynamicEvaluationTimeout->20.}]
```

or permanently using

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, {DynamicEvaluationTimeout->20.}]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: no I think it's there since version 6, but not hardly documented (it is mentioned in `tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic`)

Comment: @Albert thank you, I did not know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: ... and I didn't notice it finally became officially documented and supported in version 8, so thanks for your comment, anyway :-)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of increasing `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` globally, it is also possible to just do so locally, e.g. with something like that (as the default is 6, this would timeout with the default setting...):

```
Style[Button["TestLong", Pause[7]; Print["Result"], 
 Method -> "Preemptive"], DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 8]
```

I would, if ever possible, only change such defaults as local as possible: there are good reasons why you want dynamic calculations passed via the preemptive link to timeout. I would also rethink the design of your GUI as in general I believe it's better to use something like `Method -> "Queued"` instead of tweaking the evaluation timeout: if something takes a long time, it's probably not well fitted to be triggered through the preemptive link...

As far as I can see, the option `DynamicEvaluationTimeout` exists and seems to work since at least version 6.0.2, but was only documented in version 8 as being new.